Prepending <i> element inside <span> problem
$(document).on('click', '[showsubcommentsid]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clickitem = $(this);
    var onoffstatus = $(this).attr("OnOffStatus");
    var hasopennedonce = $(this).attr("HasOpennedOnce");
    var labeltext = $(this).attr('label');
    var topcommentid = $(this).attr("showsubcommentsid");

    if (onoffstatus == 0 && hasopennedonce == 1) {
        $('[SubCommentsDiv=' + topcommentid + ']').css('display', '');
        clickitem.prepend('<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i>');
        clickitem.text('Hide Comments');
        clickitem.attr("OnOffStatus", 1);
    }
    else if (onoffstatus == 1) {
        $('[SubCommentsDiv=' + topcommentid + ']').css('display', 'none');
        clickitem.prepend('<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>');
        clickitem.text(labeltext);
        clickitem.attr("OnOffStatus", 0);
    }

});

This code block works properly except prepending codes. I'm trying to put the i element in span element which is clickitem variable on this example but I fail.

When you call clickitem.text(labeltext), that clears out all the previous content of the element. Try adding the <i> after you set the text.

Or use  single html() call, something like clickitem.html('<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i>' + labeltext);

please add  html too so we can reproduce a practical test

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem? Also please read how do I ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.

As always: be careful of using .html("<i..></i>" + labeltext) unless you have full control of labeltext

Alternative:  clickitem.html("<i..</i><span></span>").find("span").text(labelText)

Use template literals and toggle
const shouldShow = (onoffstatus === '0' && hasopenedonce === '1');
$(`[SubCommentsDiv=${topcommentid}]`).toggle(shouldShow);

clickitem.html(`<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-${shouldShow ? 'up' : 'down' }"></i> ${shouldShow ? 'Hide Comments' : labeltext }`);
clickitem.attr("OnOffStatus", shouldShow ? '1' : '0' );


when you are calling clickitem.text(), it replaces the entire content of the clickitem element, including the  element that you just prepended.
Here is a way you can solve this:
$(document).on('click', '[showsubcommentsid]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clickitem = $(this);
    var onoffstatus = clickitem.attr("OnOffStatus");
    var hasopennedonce = clickitem.attr("HasOpennedOnce");
    var labeltext = clickitem.attr('label');
    var topcommentid = clickitem.attr("showsubcommentsid");

    if (onoffstatus == 0 && hasopennedonce == 1) {
        $('[SubCommentsDiv=' + topcommentid + ']').css('display', '');
        clickitem.html('<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i> Hide Comments');
        clickitem.attr("OnOffStatus", 1);
    } else if (onoffstatus == 1) {
        $('[SubCommentsDiv=' + topcommentid + ']').css('display', 'none');
        clickitem.html('<i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-down"></i> ' + labeltext);
        clickitem.attr("OnOffStatus", 0);
    }
});


